# My subroutine jumps to PUTS rather than the label and I don't understand why

Tags: assembly, subroutine, lc3

```
        .orig x3000
    LEA R0, TEST
    AND R1, R0, x0000
    AND R2, R0, x0000
    ADD R1, R1, x0007
    ADD R2, R2, x0002
    JSR FUNCTION_MOD

    HALT
    ; CONSTANTS

    ASCII .fill x0030   ;create ASCII mask
    NEGASCII .fill xFFD0    ;remove ASCII mask
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ; MESSAGES
TEST    .stringz "I WAS PRINTED!"
INTRO   .stringz "Calculate the modulo of a number."
PROMPT1 .stringz "Type in a number less than 65536, when finished, type a non-number character: "
PROMPT2 .stringz "Type in a number less than 65536, when finished, type a non-number character: "
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ; SUBROUTINES

    ; FUNCTION_MOD (R1, R2)
    ; R1: type integer
    ; R2: type integer
    
FUNCTION_MOD:
    STI R1, SLR1        ; store R1: a ; 7
    STI R2, SLR2        ; store R2: b ; 2
    STI R3, SLR3        ; store R3: c
    STI R4, SLR4        ; store R4: d
    PUTS
    AND R3, R0, x0000   ; c = 0
    AND R4, R0, x0000   ; d = 0
MOD_LOOP_I: 
    NOT R3, R3      ; c = -c ;-8
    ADD R3, R3, x0001       
    ADD R4, R1, R3      ; d = a + c ;-1
    BRn MOD_ELSE        ; d < 0 ;true
    NOT R3, R3      ; c = -c ;6
    ADD R3, R3, x0001   
    ADD R3, R3, R2      ; c += b ;8
    BR MOD_LOOP_I       ; loop
MOD_ELSE:
    ADD R3, R3, R2      ; c = c + 2; -6 
    ADD R4, R4, R3      ; d = a + c

    STI R4, MODR        ; save output

    LDI R1, SLR1        ; restore R1
    LDI R2, SLR2        ; restore R2
    LDI R3, SLR3        ; restore R3
    LDI R4, SLR4        ; restore R4
    RET         ; return
; Save register values during subroutines
    SLR0 .fill xA000
    SLR1 .fill xA001
    SLR2 .fill xA002
    SLR3 .fill xA003
    SLR4 .fill xA004
    SLR5 .fill xA005
    SLR6 .fill xA006
    SLR7 .fill xA007
; Function return values after subroutines
    MODR .fill xA100
.end
```

I was running this code and noticed that it wouldn't even do the JSR. So I put in a PUTS into the subroutine to make sure that it was indeed running and something else wasn't going on, however the moment I put the PUTS in, the subroutine would jump right to it. rather than to the beginning of the label, another issue is that once the subroutine reaches the RET, instead of going back to when the JSR was declared, it goes to the PUTS again so it repeats again and again. I can't figure out what is going on.

Here is a video of what happens WITHOUT PUTS being included in the subroutine
https://youtu.be/8HfBVaIwWm0

Comment: Invoking `PUTS` clobbers the return address saved in `R7`. If you want to use that, you will need to save and restore `R7`. Without the `PUTS` your code seems to run fine, but you did not say what you expect it to do and what problem you have with it apart from the `JSR` which works.

Comment: Jester is right, of course.  If you use a trap (PUTS) or call another subroutine/function, that will clobber R7.  R7 is a critical parameter to your function, it is the return address needed at the end to do `RET`/`JMP R7`.

Comment: If it works for you that's ok, but you don't need to store/restore the registers R1-R4 in indirect mode with pointers close to your code, you could just as well store/restore them close to your code directly...

Comment: @Jester that would make sense. but for some reason when I remove puts, LC3 refuses to run the subroutine all together. And why does putting the PUTs into the subroutine cause the JSR to start at PUTS rather than start at the label? The code isn't developed enough for anything to really be expected other than it goes through all of the steps. There isn't any outputs to be expected as of yet

Comment: It works here. Did you single step in the simulator? Which one do you use?

Comment: https://youtu.be/8HfBVaIwWm0
This is what happens when PUTS is not included,

Comment: If I see it correctly, you pressed the "step over" instead of the "step into" button. That will specifically skip tracing the `JSR` (but it does get executed).

Comment: Haha, that makes sense, that helps be understand some things now. I am guessing that whenever I did the test with the PUTS, since it messes up R7 that's why whenever I did the stepover it would stop at that because it would otherwise be looping indefinitely